# Show spinner while new image is loaded

Tags: javascript, image, spinner, loading

The role of the script is to change image.jpg with newimage.gif and vice versa when clicked.
**Now i want to add a spinner while the newimage.gif loads.**
Something like  9gag.com/gif.
Can someone help me please?

This is the code:
html

```
<img src="/image.jpg" id="pic" onclick="change()"/>
<a id="first" href="/newimage.gif" style="display:none;"></a>
<a id="second" href="/image.jpg" style="display:none;"></a>
```

java

```
function change(){
   var imag = document.getElementById('pic').src;
   var img = imag.slice(-3);
   var img1 = document.getElementById('second').href;
   var imag2 = document.getElementById('first').href;

   if(img == 'gif') {
      document.getElementById('pic').src=imag2;
      //    here the newimage.gif changes to image.jpg 
   } else {
      //    here the image.jpg changes to newimage.gif  
      document.getElementById('pic').src=img1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a similar one and done it like this. May be it will help you as well

```
function load_bike(imgUrl){
 old_url=$('#bike_img').attr('src');
 $('#bike_img').load( function(){
 $('.loading').css("display","none");
 $('#bike_img').css("display","block");
 }).attr('src', imgUrl);
 $('.loading').css("display","block");
 $('#bike_img').css("display","none");  
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, did not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a kind of way, the only problem is that after the image.gif gets loaded the spinner still appears.

```
if(img == 'gif') {
document.getElementById('pic').src=imag2;
//    here the newimage.gif changes back to image.jpg 
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";    
} else {
document.getElementById('pic').src=img1;

var image = new Image();
image.src = document.getElementById('second').href;

var x = image.complete;
if(x) {
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none"; 
} else {
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
}
}
}
```

This is here i use the script http://www.2lol.ro/load/poze_haioase_miscatoare/20?ref=stk

Answer (score 0):

You can show spinner, but to make it nice first you have to know the original file size or at least show it as bigger image. Without image your html element will have 0px heigh so even if you add a nice animation there you won't se it.

The best way to add and remove spinner is adding/removing a CSS class to element, for example :

```
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
pic.onload = function() {
  pic.className = '';
}

function change(){
  imag = document.getElementById('pic').src;
  var img = imag.slice(-3);
  var img1 = document.getElementById('second').href;
  var imag2 = document.getElementById('first').href;
  var pic = document.getElementById('pic');

  pic.className = 'loading';
  if(img == 'gif') {
    pic.src=imag2;
  } else {
    pic.src=img1;
  }
}
```

This sample of code will set element class attribute "loading", and then when element is loaded it will remove the element class attribute.
Then you have to create your own css that can looke like that :

```
.loading {
  background-image: url('URL_TO_IMAGE'); 
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, what do you mean? Check with Firebug/CodeInspector if it's adding proper classes.
If you are doing it on your workstation you won't see animation because loading elements on localhost is very fast.

Another thing is that you already have that elements in dom and they can be prefetched so you also won't see animation (element will send load event after few ms after assigning new value). You can test that by putting alert() statements in code, for example put `alert('loading')` before setting classname to 'loading' and `alert('element visible')` before setting classname to '';